# Tomcat 6 and DNS Lookup

Tags: tomcat, dns, lookup

I am running a web application on Tomcat 6.0.32 on CentOS 5 system.

1. As of now, only a DNS name has been registered (abcd.sg). It does not have an IP address mapped to it.
2. I have a Tomcat running at xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 and if I hit the URL http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/webappname, it shows my website.
3. How or rather where do I map the IP to the DNS so that if I hit abcd.sg it points me to http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/webappname? Can I do it on my own, or do I have to go back to the DNS registrars for doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the dns servers where to "point" the name.  So there is really no way you could totally do it yourself.  You need to update your "dns record" attached to the registered name in order to have the name map to an IP and propagate to all the various DNS servers.

If you registered the dns with someone like godaddy or similar, there are very easy to use tools on those sites to update the records for your name.  In these records you can also map subdomains, email names, and various other things.

But mostly there is nothing you can do with just the servers config by iteself. :)

Edit:

Well the DNS thing is more of an internet thing than something about your machine/server or the tools intsalled.  There are really only 3 components:

1) IP config of your machine (and your ISPs config), where you already have a working IP number and its serving pages, so thats fine.

2) The specific webserver config, where from what you said you only have one site, so you dont need to add or configure any "vitual servers".

3) And whats left is the DNS to IP mapping, which happens outside of your machine, as thats the resposibility of other servers in a sort of co-operative age old DNS server thing.  A browser asks for the IP of your server using the DNS name form the DNS servers, and then and only then will send things to your machine.

Having plesk in and of itself doesnt give you anyting but more software on your machine. Where did you buy the name from?  You need to ask them to update the DNS record or ask where you can update the DNS record to point to your IP.  And specifcally ask if installing plesk will somehow give you access to edit the DNS record.  The DNS record is elsewhere and not on your machine, and is one of the only things, for the things that matter to you, that you dont control specifically from your machine and isnt on your machine itself.

Sorry you are having trouble; hope this rather generic info helps.  Its normally very very easy these days to map the DNS to the IP, they should be able to do it for you or give you extremely specific instructions. :)

A simple test that should work from any kind of machine, windows, unix or otherwise, is to use "ping" or "tracert" or "traceroute" to get a free lookup and indication of where the dns name is currently pointing to.
Like:
`ping my.name.com`
`tracert my.name.com`

Then you should see the IP number that the record currently points to in the wild.  With tracert or traceroute you can also get an idea of where that server its pointing to lives, despite whatever you may be being told right or wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.I contacted the hosting site, they said that the configuration is possible if I have Plesk installed on my Centos system, where the DNS can be mapped? I dont want to install Plesk as then I have to again re-install MySQL..Any ideas ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Celess for your detailed info. Armed thus, I think I should be able to complete this activity. Thank you once again, and would update this thread once the mapping gets completed.

Comment: I did as u suggested and I have the IP to which this Name Server points to. Now, my website runs on another box which obviously has another IP. Now how or where do I map my website's IP to the name server's IP? or do I tell the registrar to map the NS to this IP?

Comment: I reread your comments again."You need to ask them to update the DNS record or ask where you can update the DNS record to point to your IP. And specifcally ask if installing plesk will somehow give you access to edit the DNS record. The DNS record is elsewhere and not on your machine, and is one of the only things, for the things that matter to you, that you dont control specifically from your machine and isnt on your machine itself." Will ask the hosting guys to update the DNS to point to my web server's IP..Thanks once again

Comment: At the end , we again contacted the hosting service providers where they mapped my web server's IP in their own systems. By updating the IP, the original IP I think was updated, as if I ping the site's URL, I get my webserver's IP.  Additionally, the tech. support over there also mentioned that there was a way to do that in my web server's VM as well by creating zone files thru Plesk, however,I did not pursue this avenue due to lack of time and expertise on my front. Hope this helps, some of the users who face the same prob. in the future. Thanks.